# Remove all comments from XDocument

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am working on reading XDocument. How can I remove all commented lines from XDocument.

I have tried with

```
 doc.DescendantNodes().Where(x => x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment).Remove();
```

But this removes only first level nodes with comments and inner level nodes remains as it is.

Is there any way to remove all commented lines. I believe there must be!!! ;)

Any Solutions.

Comment: Try to do `recursive`.

Comment: isnt there any workaround with single query?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of the `Where(x => x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment)` I would simply use `OfType<XComment>()`, as in

```
doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XComment>().Remove();
```

but both approaches should remove comment nodes at all levels.

Here is an example:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("../../XMLFile1.xml");

doc.Save(Console.Out);

Console.WriteLine();

doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XComment>().Remove();

doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

For a sample I get the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<!-- comment 1 -->
<root>
  <!-- comment 2 -->
  <foo>
    <!-- comment 3 -->
    <bar>foobar</bar>
  </foo>
  <!-- comment 4 -->
</root>
<!-- comment 5 -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar>foobar</bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

so all comments have been removed. If you continue to have problems then post samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Will take care in future thanx