# How to Parse XML without throwing exceptions on comments in file

Tags: vb.net, parsing, comments, xmlreader, xelement

I basically have this Code in VB.NET

```
xmlline = "<elements>etc..</elements> <!-- Some random Comment -->"
Dim XMLInput As XElement
XMLInput = XElement.Parse(xmlline)
```

and the comment is throwing and exception however i place it.
As both "double root element" and "unexpected end of comment"

and have seen some suggesting to be using this reader instead with the optional parameter

```
Dim xmlsettings As New XmlReaderSettings With {
    .IgnoreComments = True
}
XmlReader.Create(XMLtextfile, xmlsettings)
```

but cant get it to work, and furthermore, the Xelement way of accessing the different parts of the tree is working so good for me.

like doing this: `Dim XMLROOT As XElement = XMLInput.Element("ImportData").Element("UsagePoints").Element("UsagePoint")`
`XMLROOT.Element("Address").Element("Street").Value`

So how can i read XML textfiles containing XML structure with comments without getting an error ?

Comment: [Remove all comments from XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955299/7444103) -- [XComment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcomment) class.

Comment: The sample line is incorrect and shouldn't parse.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The string MUST be proper XML to work.

```
    Dim xmlline As String = "<elements><t>foo</t><t>bar</t><!-- Some random Comment --></elements>"
    Dim XMLInput As XElement
    XMLInput = XElement.Parse(xmlline)
```

edit:

```
    Dim comment As String = "Some random Comment"
    Dim xmlline As String = "<elements><t>foo</t><t>bar</t></elements>"
    Dim XMLInput As XElement
    XMLInput = XElement.Parse(xmlline)

    Dim xdoc As New XDocument(XMLInput)
    xdoc.Add(New XComment(comment))
```

Comment: nope, comments outside the elements is allowed in the XML standard

https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/
i just need to sanitize it cuz te XElement.parse function cant handle it, so how to.

Comment: @Gabriel - the standard says, "...in a document outside other markup;" XElement is NOT a document.  See edit for possible work around.

Comment: Thats adding a comment ? but now i understand that Xdocument can remove all comments as per @jimi ´s link, and it worked like a charm. And in the XML, the <!-- is way outside all the elements ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jimi in the comments to pointing me to the answer in this link
[Remove all comments from XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952718/remove-all-comments-from-xdocument/21955299#21955299)

This is how i solved it:

```
Dim fs As New FileStream(myfiles(y).FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
Dim sr As New StreamReader(fs)
line = sr.ReadToEnd
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(line)
doc.DescendantNodes.OfType(Of XComment).Remove
line = doc.ToString
```

and yes, i cant use the LOAD function in xdocument or any other cuz the file i´m trying to read is in use by another process, but this works like a charm!